# How To Fix Python Threading Module Problem

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, python-multithreading

In the code below, when I press Button 1, the application does not respond and I cannot use other Button 2.
Threading module was required for this.
I have created Threads for Threadingle main() and process(), but when the program opens and I press Button 1, the application does not respond and I cannot press Button 2.
What's the problem?

```
from tkinter import *
import threading

def process():
    while True:
        print("Hello World")
processThread = threading.Thread(target=process)

def main():

    mainWindow = Tk()
    mainWindow.resizable(FALSE, FALSE)

    mainWindow.title("Text")
    mainWindow.geometry("500x250")

    recButton=Button(mainWindow)
    recButton.config(text="Button 1", font=("Arial", "13"), bg="red",fg="white", width="15", command=processThread.run)
    recButton.place(x=15,y=10)

    stopButton=Button(mainWindow)
    stopButton.config(text="Button 2", font=("Calibri", "13"), bg="orange",fg="white", width="15", command="")
    stopButton.place(x=15,y=55)

    textBox = Text(mainWindow, height="14", width="37")
    textBox.place(x=180, y=10)

    mainWindow.mainloop()
mainThread = threading.Thread(target=main)
mainThread.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

use **processThread.start** to start the thread instead of processThread.run infact processThread.run will just call the process method and which will not return control to your **event loop** hence application goes wild

> command=processThread.start

```
from tkinter import *
import threading

def process():
    while True:
        print("Hello World")
processThread = threading.Thread(target=process)

def main():

    mainWindow = Tk()
    mainWindow.resizable(FALSE, FALSE)

    mainWindow.title("Text")
    mainWindow.geometry("500x250")

    recButton=Button(mainWindow)
    recButton.config(text="Button 1", font=("Arial", "13"), bg="red",fg="white", width="15", command=processThread.start)
    recButton.place(x=15,y=10)

    stopButton=Button(mainWindow)
    stopButton.config(text="Button 2", font=("Calibri", "13"), bg="orange",fg="white", width="15", command="")
    stopButton.place(x=15,y=55)

    textBox = Text(mainWindow, height="14", width="37")
    textBox.place(x=180, y=10)

    mainWindow.mainloop()
mainThread = threading.Thread(target=main)
mainThread.start()
```

Modified the above code for **start** and **stop** button functionality. Here we are using `flag` when this is true thread will be running if flag if `false` the thread will `stop`. Remember we can't `start` a `stopped thread` because of this we have to create `new thread`.

```
import time
from tkinter import *
import threading

flag = True


def printHello():
    global flag
    while flag:
        print("Hello World")
        time.sleep(1)

"""
starts the thread
"""
def startProcess():
    global flag
    flag = True
    processThread = threading.Thread(target=printHello)
    processThread.start()

"""
stops the thread
"""
def stopProcess():
    global flag
    flag = False


def main():
    mainWindow = Tk()
    mainWindow.resizable(FALSE, FALSE)

    mainWindow.title("Text")
    mainWindow.geometry("500x250")

    recButton = Button(mainWindow)
    recButton.config(text="Button 1", font=("Arial", "13"), bg="red", fg="white", width="15",
                     command=startProcess)
    recButton.place(x=15, y=10)

    stopButton = Button(mainWindow)
    stopButton.config(text="Button 2", font=("Calibri", "13"), bg="orange", fg="white", width="15", command=stopProcess)
    stopButton.place(x=15, y=55)

    textBox = Text(mainWindow, height="14", width="37")
    textBox.place(x=180, y=10)

    mainWindow.mainloop()


mainThread = threading.Thread(target=main)
mainThread.start()
```